# when accessing an object field using get method,value always undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i wrote a TypeScript model and i wrote a get method :

```
get comments(): [any] {
  return this.commentsTest;
}
set comments(comments: [any]) {
  this.commentsTest = comments;
}
```

the field it self is defined as private :

```
private commentsTest: [any];
```

in the constructor i initialized the object as follow :

```
this.comments = commentsTest;
```

when i am trying to use that field using the get method it is always undefined,
but if i am accessing it directly(while getting access warning)
i do get the values i am looking for :

```
openExtendedDetailsModal(comments) {
  console.log("***" + this.investorObject.comments); // undefined
  console.log(this.investorObject.commentsTest); // defined
  //this.commentsdDetails.altOpen(comments);
}
```

**UPDATE**
here is the code i am using :

```
investorObject: Investor;
prametersSubscription: Subscription;
id: string;

constructor(private investorService: InvestorsService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.prametersSubscription = this.route.params.subscribe(
    (params: Params) => {
      this.id = params.id;
      this.getInvestorData();
    }
  );
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.prametersSubscription.unsubscribe();
}

getInvestorData() {
  this.investorService.getSingleInvestorById(this.id).subscribe(
    data => {
      this.investorObject = data.data;
      console.log(this.investorObject.commentsTest);
    });
}

openExtendedDetailsModal(comments) {
  console.log("***" + this.investorObject.lastName); // defined
  console.log("***" + this.investorObject.comments); // undefined
  console.log(this.investorObject.commentsTest); // defined
  //this.commentsdDetails.altOpen(comments);
}
```

here is part of the Investor class :
[image]
what am i missing here ?

Thanks

Comment: How is `this.investorObject` declared?

Comment: Where is `this.commentsTest` initialized to a value?

Comment: yes.all other fields are populated and the data is available.
for example i am also using  :  this.investorObject.lastName which is also has set/get and i do no have that problem.

it is getting the data from http call the entire object is populated except this field @Pointy

Comment: Well because you have not posted that code, it's very difficult to help.

Comment: added the code.
the comments i am sending to "openExtendedDetailsModal" is just something i tried ti test,it should not get value and instead just using "this.investorObject.comments"

Comment: you must write this.investorObject =new Invertor(data.data), else this.investorObject only will have the "properties, not the method of the object

Comment: Thanks @Eliseo ,tried to do that,still getting the same issue,undefined.
will try to recreate the DB i suspecting the the issue is coming from the field comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i manged to solve this issue,

i have changed the model as followed :

1)changed the constructor

```
constructor() {}
```

2)changed the name and the type of the commentsTest field:

```
private commentsTest: [Object];
```

3)Initiated as followed :

```
this.investorObject = new Investor();
Object.assign(this.investorObject, data.data as Investor);
```

so now ,i am getting the comments as i wanted to,also the type of the object is Investor.

[image]

Thanks all